# get specific value from array

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array:

```
    stdClass Object
(
    [nid] =&gt; 218
    [node_title] =&gt; This is my title text
    [field_data_field_slider_image_delta] =&gt; 0
    [field_data_field_slider_image_language] =&gt; und
    [field_data_field_slider_image_bundle] =&gt; slider
    [field_data_field_slider_image_field_slider_image_fid] =&gt; 1278
    [field_data_field_slider_image_field_slider_image_alt] =&gt; 
    [field_data_field_slider_image_field_slider_image_title] =&gt; 
    [field_data_field_slider_image_field_slider_image_width] =&gt; 1180
    [field_data_field_slider_image_field_slider_image_height] =&gt; 352
    [node_created] =&gt; 1334267878
    [field_data_field_slider_link_node_entity_type] =&gt; node
    [field_data_body_node_entity_type] =&gt; node
    [field_data_field_slider_image_node_entity_type] =&gt; node
    [_field_data] =&gt; Array
        (
            [nid] =&gt; Array
                (
                    [entity_type] =&gt; node
                    [entity] =&gt; stdClass Object
                        (
                            [vid] =&gt; 218
                            [uid] =&gt; 1
                            [title] =&gt; This is my title text
                            [log] =&gt; 
                            [status] =&gt; 1
                            [comment] =&gt; 1
                            [promote] =&gt; 1
                            [sticky] =&gt; 0
                            [nid] =&gt; 218
                            [type] =&gt; slider
                            [language] =&gt; en
                            [created] =&gt; 1334267878
                            [changed] =&gt; 1334268388
                            [tnid] =&gt; 0
                            [translate] =&gt; 0
                            [revision_timestamp] =&gt; 1334268388
                            [revision_uid] =&gt; 1
                            [body] =&gt; Array
                                (
                                    [und] =&gt; Array
                                        (
                                            [0] =&gt; Array
                                                (
                                                    [value] =&gt; <p>This is my body text</p>
                                                    [summary] =&gt; 
                                                    [format] =&gt; full_html
                                                    [safe_value] =&gt;  <p>This is my body text</p> 
                                                    [safe_summary] =&gt;   
                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                            [field_slider_image] =&gt; Array
                                (
                                    [und] =&gt; Array
                                        (
                                            [0] =&gt; Array
                                                (
                                                    [fid] =&gt; 1278
                                                    [alt] =&gt; 
                                                    [title] =&gt; 
                                                    [width] =&gt; 1180
                                                    [height] =&gt; 352
                                                    [uid] =&gt; 1
                                                    [filename] =&gt; slider-d.jpg
                                                    [uri] =&gt; public://images/slider-d.jpg
                                                    [filemime] =&gt; image/jpeg
                                                    [filesize] =&gt; 103135
                                                    [status] =&gt; 1
                                                    [timestamp] =&gt; 1334267878
                                                    [type] =&gt; image
                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                            [field_slider_link] =&gt; Array
                                (
                                    [und] =&gt; Array
                                        (
                                            [0] =&gt; Array
                                                (
                                                    [url] =&gt; http://mydomain.com/my/link
                                                    [title] =&gt; 
                                                    [attributes] =&gt; Array
                                                        (
                                                        )

                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                            [cid] =&gt; 0
                            [last_comment_timestamp] =&gt; 1334267878
                            [last_comment_name] =&gt; 
                            [last_comment_uid] =&gt; 1
                            [comment_count] =&gt; 0
                            [name] =&gt; admin
                            [picture] =&gt; 1242
                            [data] =&gt; a:2:{s:7:"contact";i:0;s:7:"overlay";i:1;}
                        )

                )

        )

    [field_field_slider_link] =&gt; Array
        (
            [0] =&gt; Array
                (
                    [rendered] =&gt; Array
                        (
                            [#markup] =&gt; http://mydomain.com/my/link
                            [#access] =&gt; 1
                        )

                    [raw] =&gt; Array
                        (
                            [url] =&gt; http://mydomain.com/my/link
                            [title] =&gt; http://mydomain.com/my/link
                            [attributes] =&gt; Array
                                (
                                )

                            [display_url] =&gt; http://mydomain.com/my/link
                        )

                )

        )

    [field_body] =&gt; Array
        (
            [0] =&gt; Array
                (
                    [rendered] =&gt; Array
                        (
                            [#markup] =&gt;  <p>This is my body text</p> 
                            [#access] =&gt; 1
                            [#type] =&gt; markup
                            [#pre_render] =&gt; Array
                                (
                                    [0] =&gt; drupal_pre_render_markup
                                    [1] =&gt; ctools_dependent_pre_render
                                )

                            [#children] =&gt;  <p>This is my body text</p> 
                            [#printed] =&gt; 1
                        )

                    [raw] =&gt; Array
                        (
                            [value] =&gt; <p>This is my body text</p>
                            [summary] =&gt; 
                            [format] =&gt; full_html
                            [safe_value] =&gt;  <p>This is my body text</p> 
                            [safe_summary] =&gt;   
                            [#children] =&gt; 
                            [#printed] =&gt; 1
                        )

                    [#children] =&gt;  <p>This is my body text</p> 
                    [#printed] =&gt; 1
                )

            [#children] =&gt;  <p>This is my body text</p> 
            [#printed] =&gt; 1
        )

    [field_field_slider_image] =&gt; Array
        (
            [0] =&gt; Array
                (
                    [rendered] =&gt; Array
                        (
                            [#theme] =&gt; image_formatter
                            [#item] =&gt; Array
                                (
                                    [fid] =&gt; 1278
                                    [alt] =&gt; 
                                    [title] =&gt; 
                                    [width] =&gt; 1180
                                    [height] =&gt; 352
                                    [uid] =&gt; 1
                                    [filename] =&gt; slider-d.jpg
                                    [uri] =&gt; public://images/slider-d.jpg
                                    [filemime] =&gt; image/jpeg
                                    [filesize] =&gt; 103135
                                    [status] =&gt; 1
                                    [timestamp] =&gt; 1334267878
                                    [type] =&gt; image
                                )

                            [#image_style] =&gt; featured_slideshow
                            [#path] =&gt; 
                            [#access] =&gt; 1
                        )

                    [raw] =&gt; Array
                        (
                            [fid] =&gt; 1278
                            [alt] =&gt; 
                            [title] =&gt; 
                            [width] =&gt; 1180
                            [height] =&gt; 352
                            [uid] =&gt; 1
                            [filename] =&gt; slider-d.jpg
                            [uri] =&gt; public://images/slider-d.jpg
                            [filemime] =&gt; image/jpeg
                            [filesize] =&gt; 103135
                            [status] =&gt; 1
                            [timestamp] =&gt; 1334267878
                            [type] =&gt; image
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

and I need to get the `[url]` value (which in this one is `http://mydomain.com/my/link`)

I tried to follow a tutorial and ended up with this:

```
print $row->field_field_slider_link[0]['raw']['url']
```

but I get this error message:

```
Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in include() (line 57 of /var/www/vhosts/clientname/public_html/sites/all/themes/custom/templates/views/ff-nivo-slider/views-view-fields--ff-nivo-slider.tpl.php).
```

can anyone see what i'm doing wrong here?

Thanks
C

Comment: the offset error occur when the array key or element not availble

Comment: Hi @RaviJethva. That key is definitely available. it there anything else that could cause this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The array your code runs with is not the one you expect. Check the value of `$row->field_field_slider_link`. Chances are that it's an empty array.

Comment: but there is always a link. should I go for `[field_slider_link]` insted or i sthat the same issue?

Comment: Why are you so certain that there is always a link? Please make sure to check that. You can't simply go and replace random indices, in the same way that you can't replace random digits in a phone number and expect to reach the desired person.

Comment: I ran `$row->field_field_slider_link` and got this: `Array
([0] =&gt; Array
        (
            [rendered] =&gt; Array
                (
                    [#markup] =&gt; http://mydomain.com/my/link
                    [#access] =&gt; 1
                )
            [raw] =&gt; Array
                (
                    [url] =&gt; http://mydomain.com/my/link
                    [title] =&gt; http://mydomain.com/my/link
                    [attributes] =&gt; Array
                        (
                        )
                    [display_url] =&gt; http://mydomain.com/my/link)))
`

Comment: hi @phihag, any other sugestions here?